# No known class method for selector 'application:openURL:options:sourceApplication:annotation'

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, fitbit

I am integrating Fitbit into my react-native app and there is a piece of code that I should add to my AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "RCTLinkingManager.h"


@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
      openURL:(NSURL *)url
      sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
      annotation:(id)annotation {
        return [RCTLinkingManager
                application:application
                openURL:url
                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                annotation:annotation];
      }
```

but I already have that set up that handles FB login and firebase linking and maybe something else:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
    openURL:(NSURL *)url
    options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {
   if ([[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:app openURL:url options:options]) {
      return YES;
    }

    if ([RCTLinkingManager application:app openURL:url options:options]) {
      return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

and when I'm trying to combine them into that:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
       openURL:(NSURL *)url
       options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
       sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
        annotation:(id)annotation{
    if ([[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:app openURL:url options:options ]) {
       return YES;
     }

     if ([RCTLinkingManager application:app
           openURL:URL
           options:options
           sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
           annotation:(id)annotation ]) {
       return YES;
     }

     return NO;
 }
```

I'm getting the error: `No known class method for selector 'application:openURL:options:sourceApplication:annotation'`

Is it mean that `sourceApplication` and `annotation` are already included into `options`?

Any help welcome

Answer (score 0):

you should call the `FBSDKApplicationDelegate` differently:

```
    if ([[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation]) {
        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: I need to change the part with ```LinkingManager```, not with ```FBSDKApplicationDelegate```

Comment: there is a typo in your call, you entered `URL`, but it should be `url`.

Comment: yes, it was a typo here, ```FBSDKApplicationDelegate``` worked good